# Generate packages and dev-packages in Pipfile to requirements.txt

Tags: python, pipenv

How can I generate all packages (include dev-package) in Pipfile to requirements.txt?
I have `pytest` in my `dev-package` list.
I try to run `pipenv lock -r > requirements.txt` but it just generate `pakcage` list to requirements.txt. `pytest` is not generated, there is no `dev-package` generated.
Then I try to run `pipenv lock -r -d > requirements.txt` but is just generate `dev-packages`.